# Why does the wrap_content in imageview not make it much bigger based on the actual width?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview, android-resources, android-resolution

I have an `ImageView` that has:

```
android:layout_height="100dp"   
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:scaleType="fitCenter" 
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

What I see is that if I set an image that has as dimensions (based on the info of my pc) `1280px854`
If I open it in my pc the image looks huge.
The same image is small in my `ImageView` although I have set `wrap_content`.
I am not sure I get how this works. E.g. 1280/4 = 320dpi (xxxhdpi) but for with `wrap_content` the image view does not have as width `320dpi`
To clarify: I am trying to understand why it works like that and does not make it bigger with `wrap_content`.

Comment: Are you actually using height or layout_height (same for width)?

Comment: you've set the height, hence, wrap content for the width will preserve the ratio of the image (x, y)

Comment: @DanielBeleza: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the post

Comment: @Mitch: Is there some formula so we know what is the max width it can have respecting this ratio?

Comment: When you have the height specified and width set to `wrap_content`, the width already implies max-width with regards to the ratio. If you're interested in how much that exactly is then: width = height * (1280 * 854). In this case 150-ish

Comment: @Mitch: That 150 is it dp? Yes that is what I am trying to understand. How these values work together

Comment: @Jim Yes, that's dp. If you were to put pixels in the formula (for the height), then that would give you pixels back for the width. If I put this down into an answer, would you accept it?

Comment: @Mitch: I would if you elaborated it on it so I can understand how this multiplication holds up to give the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's talk about the ratio of your image. It's 1280px wide and 854px tall, hence, its proportion is **1280/854 ≈ 3/2**.

Second, you've set the height of your `ImageView` to `100dp`. If the width is not specified, then android will try its best to perceive the ratio (3/2) and will calculate the width:

```
ratio = width/height
3/2 = width/100
width = 150dp
```

Notice it gave us `dp`, if we were to plug `px` instead(for the height) it will give us px back.

Third, now that we have the size of the image (150dp x 100dp) and `width='wrap_content'` the width of the imageView will correspond to the 150dp

Comment: In your earlier comment you wrote `width = height * (1280 * 854).` Was that supposed to be `width = height * (1280 / 854).`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` since the 100dp in layout_height was limiting the "growth" of image width.

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I don't have a problem with the current display. I am asking how it works

Answer (score 0):

This atribute:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

means that the original aspect ratio of the image will be preserved. 
You want to fit that image an an `ImageView` with:

```
android:layout_height="100dp"
```

so since you constraint the height of the image, if it is bigger that 100dp it will shrink to that height and its width will shrink proportionally.

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I don't have a problem with the current display. I am asking how it works

Comment: As I mention in my answer: *the original aspect ratio of the image will be preserved* this is what `fitCenter` does.

Comment: That is helpful indeed. But can we know how much the width could expand while preserving that ratio at the same time?

Comment: Proportionally means that if the height will be the 1/3 of the original height, then the same will apply to width, since you don't place any constraint to the width.

Comment: See these links: https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-for-android-imageview-scaletype-and-adjustviewbounds-64a1e4a35503 and https://abhiandroid.com/ui/scaletype-imageview-example.html